# Why is operator concatanation in java allowed?

Tags: java

So as the title states, why is this in java allowed?

```
int x = 0;
x = +-+-+-+-+-+-+-4;
```

It has no use, and it allows bugs very hard to spot.

Comment: it has its own use, it is called [unary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) , you can write code without this operator too which has bugs very hard to spot

Comment: Maybe they didn't think anybody would ever write code like that.

Comment: Every language allows you to shoot yourself in the foot if you wanted to.

Comment: You are doing it wrong.

Comment: If the expression is parseable, why not allow it? You'd have the compiler waste time looking for things like this? Mayber a linter... Also, I think it's very easy to spot where the bug might be in that code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `+anything` is allowed, and `-anything` is allowed. It's like asking why `thing.getThing().getThing().getThing().getThing().getThing().getThing().getThing().getThing().getThing().getThing().getThing().getThing().getThing().getThing().getThing()` is allowed - they're not going to add artificial limits just to try and stop people writing bad code.

`+-+-+-+-+-+-+-4` is the same as `+(-(+(-(+(-(+(-(+(-(+(-(+(-4)))))))))))))`.